# ruby curses: How to get ctrl/meta keys with

Tags: ruby, curses

Im trying to `Curses.getchr`, but keys like <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> are not captured, is there any lib that would allow me to capture them and best of all something intuitive/readable like

```
FooBar.bind('Ctrl+s'){ raise "dont save!" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> is usually grabbed by the terminal, so you have to put `Curses` in raw mode to capture that key.  Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'curses'

Curses.raw # intercept everything
Curses.noecho
loop do
  case Curses.getch
    when ?q     then break
    when ?b     then Curses.addch ?b
    when ?\C-s  then Curses.addstr "^s" # Ctrl+S
  end
end
```